# Delay Tasks in a C++ Windows App (Sleep)

Tags: c++, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am currently writing a little Windows 10 app in VS 2015 in C++. I am trying to follow this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cpp

Now I have a little loop that looks like this:

```
while (getline(file, line))
    {
    i++;
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    //Sleep(300);
    MyApp::MainPage::outBox->Text = ref new PLatform::String(to_wstring(i).c_str());}
```

I want the loop to wait a few hundred ms in order to continually change the content of a textbox. What the methods i tried achieved was that the output itself was delayed but the counting was continued, so that nothing changed until after the accumulated wait times. So the ouput goes from 0 to 50 after a few seconds instead of 0->1-2->3... every 300 ms. I thought that maybe this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Is a solution, but I cant get it to work in C++. The Class System::Threading has no member Task or Tasks...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that loop in your main thread?

Comment: Im not sure what a main thread is in the uwa context, but it is within a pressed event of an inputbox.

Comment: This looks like it might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806809/c-equivalent-of-nets-task-delay

Comment: I'm not an expert in UWP dev but it seems like you are blocking your main/ui thread by sleeping in your while loop which prevents the ui from updating which is why you are not seeing a gradual update. You need some kind of timer that triggers aftert a certain time and invokes some callback. Make sure that the callback is executed on the ui thread if you wish to update the ui. Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Comment: @PetterHesselberg well it is relevant but unanswered, I think? The Concurrency::task method does not work for me either.